# I want to make multi-node , not private network

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I know how to make multi-node in private network,

but I have a question how to make a multi-node with other machines.

[image]

this picture shows independent two nodes, and you can see blank on admin.peers

my first geth

> geth --networkid 8484 --datadir test_data --port "30303" --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover  --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner,debug,txpool" console

my second geth

> geth --networkid 8484 --datadir test_data2 --port "30304" --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport "8546" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover  --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner,debug,txpool" console

I had a successful result on private Network, but nothing on different node
maybe, nobody has no idea but very Thank you for any answers!